# store a sql value into a string variable in java

Tags: java, sql

I want to get the value from the table in the column Street..

I have:

```
Street = "SELECT strStreet FROM tblLocations WHERE" +
            " strLocations='" + Location + "';";
```

which I just figured out doesn't work when I later try and print out street is just prints as that string above rather than the value

this is what i have and it keeps returning that the value of street is null

```
    Street = "SELECT strStreet FROM tblLocations WHERE" +
            " strLocations='" + Location + "';";

    try {
        //create, execute and close the stmt
        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Street);
        while(rs.next()){
            street = rs.getString("strAddress1");
        }
        System.out.println(street);
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("there was an issue updating");
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }
```

Comment: Don't you have to execute the query first, in order to retrieve the value?

Comment: you have to actually run the query against your database if you want to get data from the database.

Comment: `String money = "Give me money please";`

Comment: Run the query if you face issues, please show the code and the issue.Really basic jdbc

Comment: Post what have you tried so far?

Comment: in my understanding you're printing the 'Street' string? something like Sys...print(Street)? if thats the case then sure you get the string you've just defined.
you need to execute the query ('Street' is the string query) and get the result. The result is not the string 'Street' itself

Comment: I have Street as the query and i wanna store the result of that in street (lowercasE)

Comment: You wrote a couple errors here: first - your SQL query allows SQL Injection and contains unnecessary semicolon. Second - you select field `strStreet`, but fetch `strAddress1`. Third, you iterate over all resultset, but output only one last value.

Comment: I do not understand too but according to what I understand from your code, **rs.getString("strAddress1")** is wrong, should be **rs.getString("strStreet");**, if that's not the problem, maybe is in the query when you try filter a field strLocations **strLocations='Location'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rest works, you are selecting only the `strStreet` column in your query, but you're trying to extract a `strAddress1` column from your result set.